# SQLite Database fetching on other than main UI thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, sqlite

On tableview show lot of data from sqlite database with multiple mapping table.On tableview cell show average data from mapping table with mapping table average sum.That calculation part is need to done on other than UI thread and if calculated then reload on tableview cell like leasy loading.Please help me for that task how to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help,

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    //Do your calculation here
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //Reload Tableview here
}
```

Comment: Can you identify the reason for crash? Or please attach the crash log in the question itself. So it might be helpful and everyone can understand the problem easily

Comment: I had tried that solution already. But SQLite database, data fetch operation is on secondary thread that crashes my application.I am using FMDB database  with FMDBDataBaseQueue in sync manner.Please give me solution for database crash avoid in background.

Comment: Thanks for reply.The reason for crash is on background thread perform multiple fetch request query and same time execute two query on database that locks the database and crash the application on FMDB library for line while(next) record fetch.